# Path is not matching

Tags: python, django

I have started learning Django and I was watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SeJIm7QkU7I&list=PLhQjrBD2T380xvFSUmToMMzERZ3qB5Ueu&index=5) lecture (till starting 20 minutes) and following the instructions but I am getting the error as :

```
 Page not found (404)  
 Request Method:    GET
 Request URL:   http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello

 Using the URLconf defined in lecture3.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

 admin/

 The current path, hello, didn't match any of these.

 You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. 
 Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

After running

```
python3 manage.py runserver
```

My settings.py file in "lecture3" app is :

```
 # Application definition

 INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'hello',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
   'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 ]
```

and some other content.

views.py file in "hello" app is :

```
 from django.http import HttpResponse
 from django.shortcuts import render

 # Create your views here.
 def index(request):
     return HttpResponse("Hello World!")
```

urls.py file in "hello" app is :

```
 from django.urls import path

 from . import views

 urlpatterns=[
     path("",views.index, name="index")
 ]
```

urls.py file in "lecture3" app is :

```
    from django.contrib import admin    
    from django.urls import include, path       

    urlpatterns = [
       path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
       path('/hello/', include('hello.urls'))
    ]
```

I have checked similar questions here but my problem was not resolved. Can anyone please tell why I am getting this error. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The problem is the way you are defining the the path. Change /hello/ to hello/ in your urls.py. It might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```
...
   path('/hello/', include('hello.urls'))
...
```

Remove the first slash from the path:

```
...
   path('hello/', include('hello.urls'))
...
```

Then you need to access it with a trailing slash `/` as follows `http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello/`

Or with Django's conventions, use `APPEND_SLASH=True` in your `settings.py` so accessing `http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello` will redirect to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello/`

Comment: It is not working. It is showing same error. @GrandPhuba

Comment: @ankit updated answer. Try changing the URL to 
`path('hello/', include('hello.urls'))`

Comment: Thank you @GrandPhuba.